# Play a sound alert when Finder is done copying files

Tags: finder, macos

I would like Finder to play a sound alert when it is done copying files. How can I do this? I'm using Mavericks.

Comment: Is the default sound not enough  ?

Comment: I actually thought there wasn't one, so apparently not.

Comment: A notification would be nice for people who have their sound off all the time